# The maximum number of objects that can be instantiated with a Django model?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-2.7, architecture

I wrote an app to record the user interactions with the website search box,
the query string is saved as an object of the model `SearchQuery`. Whenever a user enters some data in the search box, I can save the search query and some info related to the query on the database.
This is for the idea of getting the search trends,

the fields in my database models are,

1. A Character Field (max_length=30)
2. A PositiveIntegerField
3. A BooleanField

My Questions are,

1. How many objects can be instantiated from the model `SearchQuery`? If there is a limit on numbers?
2. As the objects are not related (no db relationships) should I use MongoDB or some kind of NoSQLs for performance?
3. Is this a good design or should I do some more work to make it efficient?

Django version 1.6.5

Python version 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > How many objects can be instantiated from the model SearchQuery? If there is a limit on numbers?

   As many as your chosen database can handle, this is probably in the millions. If you are concerned you can use a scheduler to delete older queries when they are no longer useful.
2. > As the objects are not related (no db relationships) should I use MongoDB or some kind of NoSQLs for performance?

   Could you, but its unlikely to give you much (if any efficiency gains). Because you are doing frequent writes and (presumably) infrequent reads, then its unlikely to hit the database very hard at all.
3. > Is this a good design or should I do some more work to make it efficient?

   There are probably two recommendations I'd make.

   a. If you are going to be doing frequent reads on the Search log, [look at using multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/). One for your log, and one for everything else.

   b. Consider just using a regular log file for this information. Again, you will probably only be examining this data infrequently. So there are strng arguments to piping it into a log file, probably CSV-like, to make data analysis of it easier.